# After logging in (in my Django app) I get the 403 error

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-csrf

When I run my Django application (via `python manage.py runserver`) I get the login screen, however when I try to login it redirect me to the page that says:

> Forbidden (403)
>   CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Here is my settings.py

```py
"""
Django settings for my_app project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '...'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cooking_book'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], 
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_app.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

There are questions similar to mine here on stackoverflow but unfortunately the answers are not helpful to me...

Additional notes on what I tried:

- I am allowing cookies in my browser.
- My view functions pass a request to the template's `render` method.
- In the template I am adding `{% csrf_token %}` inside each POST form.
- I also tried setting the `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None` and `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False` but it made no difference.

It would be great if anyone could help me with this, I am really stuck...

**EDIT:**
If you give me thumbs down, can you please just let me know what I did wrong? I am new here, still adapting... and if this is too easy for you and that is the reason for the thumbs down, please leave an answer I will appreciate it. Thank you!

**2nd EDIT:** Adding the relevant parts of the template and views.py file, where the csrf token is used. It is also worth mentioning that when the user logs in he/she is supposed to go to the homepage (that contains no POST forms and consequently no csrf tokens), and chose where to go next.

views.py  (relevant part)

```py
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def dining(request):

    #request is POST when user filters the city
    if request.method == 'POST':
        filter_city = FilterCityForm(request.POST)
        if filter_city.is_valid():
            filter_city = filter_city.save(commit=False)
            city = str(filter_city.name)
#...
# here I'm doing some calculations and querying depending on the chosen city
#...
        filter_city = FilterCityForm(initial={'name':city})

    else:
        filter_city = FilterCityForm(initial={'name':'Toronto'})

    return render(request, 'dining.html', {'filter_city':filter_city})
```

dining.html (relevant part):

```html
<div name='dropdown'>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

  City: {% for widget in filter_city %}
                {% if widget.errors %}
                    {% for error in widget.errors %}
                        <span style="color: red">{{ error }}</span><br>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                {{ widget }}
           {% endfor %}

         <input  type="submit" value="OK">

    </form>
    <br>

</div>
```

Comment: can you show your `template` file where you put  `{% csrf_token %}` and the `views.py` where you render it.

Comment: @KushanGunasekera Sure, I can post them, but also, the thing is that once I log in it should take me to the homepage, from which I chose the next action. On that page there are no POST forms, and consequently no ```{% csrf_token %}``` template tag.

Comment: Hi @KushanGunasekera , I added the relevant part of the template and views.py. Do you see anything I should fix?